# Need simplified function for onclick button sounds

Tags: javascript, button, audio

This is my first question here sorry if I make any mistake.

I want to know how to simplify an action (function), I have a drumkit with different buttons and sounds, I'm using this code: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pL23q6g1/3/)

JS

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

How can I write just one function and play different sounds for every button?

Answer (score 0):

You could try firing multiple functions from one function. Something like:

```
<button onClick="play()">song1</button>
<button onClick="play()">song2</button>
<button onClick="play()">song3</button>

function someFunc() {
    function audioOne() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }
    else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    };
    function audioTwo() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio2');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }
    else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    };
    function audioThree() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio3');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }
    else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    };
}
```

**Alternatively** you could also try something like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("id");
audio.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("audio1 triggered")}, false);
audio.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("audio2 triggered")}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function play(id) {
var audio = document.getElementById(id);
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
}else{
    audio.currentTime = 0
}
```

call it like this:

```
play('audio1');
play('audio2');
```

If i understand your question correctly this should work for your use-case. You basically just pass the elements id as parameter. Everytime you call the function the logic will apply to the element you specified as parameter in your function call.